# How to tell size of Eagle library component?

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-design

I am working on my very first PCB design using Eagle. In my design, I will be using a [10W 10 Ohm power resistor](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=CP001010R00JE14virtualkey61300000virtualkey71-CP001010R00JE14). Since it isn't a "standard" size, I'm having trouble finding the component in Eagle. In particular, it has a width of 47mm.

No component in rcl.lbr is long enough. resistor-power.lbr seems pretty promising, but many  of the components don't have measurements. And I'm not sure what the closest equivalent is. For example, KH216-8 seems like it is roughly the right size. And it happens to have a measurement. So is it, uh, "safe" to go with that?

How could I view the dimensions of a component if it's not in the description?

Are there any other techniques I can use when trying to find a library part that approximates the component I've chosen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way around this. I would open up the *resistor-power.lbr* library on its own, in the library editor, open up the first footprint (ACO1), change the major grid to *10mm*, then go through each one and note those that are close. There's usually some kind of logic to the footprint names and numbers -- for this library, it appears the *letter prefix denote a width* class and the *number denotes length*. <sup>***EDIT1:***</sup> I went and did this, and none are 47mm wide.
<sup>***EDIT2:***</sup> After looking at the datasheet, it appears it is 47mm long and only 9mm wide, which fits **HPS947**. (**KH216-8**, **RS10-38-39**, and **RWM8X45** also seem to fit... sorta.)

In almost every PCB design you will be making your own parts. I find it useful to make a new EAGLE library for every project, and copy all used part into it. The easiest way to make a new part, if it's just a variation of another, is to copy symbols and possibly even footprints into a new layout, then edit them. For this part, you can copy the *power-resistor.lbr > R* symbol by opening it up as if you were going to edit it, selecting the whole thing with the **Group** function, then copying the group with the **Copy** function (click **Copy** button, right-click previously grouped symbol, select *"Copy: Group"*. This puts the whole thing into your *Paste Buffer*:

- [image] *<-- (that button)*

Open up a new library, *example.lbr*, then create a new symbol *(Library > Symbol)*. Click the **Insert Paste Buffer** button *( ^-- that button)*. The copied symbol should come up, labels and all -- click on the crosshairs to line it up with the symbol anchor. I usually make my own footprints simply to remove all doubt in the library specs, but they can be copied using the same method. Another way to copy a part is to copy the entire library and rename it, then edit the entire thing. ***[Sparkfun also has a pretty good tutorial on making parts.](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110)***

Also, when I make my own parts, I fill out the caption so I won't have to browse the footprints directly in the future!

Comment: Ah, sorry for confusing the "length" and "width" measurements. This was quite helpful. Thank you!